# How to recognize corrupt image files in folder while training using Keras

Tags: keras

I am using Keras ImageDataGenerator with flow_from_directory.

For training data, each class folder has 10,000-20,000 jpg files each, with 13 classes. While training, every hour or so, before full data has been trained once, I get error from Keras indicating that a particular jpg file could not be read. Sure enough, I explore into the file location, and can see file is corrupt.
problem is this wastes lot of time, and on each error, I have to restart the training.

1. is there a way to modify Keras flow_from_directory or    to ensure that corrupt files are skipped and training goes on without error
2. if 1 is not possible, is there a way to quickly(I have 1.1 TB of data) verify corrput files in all class folders and remove them /delete them from those folders, before starting the training.

Comment: https://opensource.com/article/17/2/python-tricks-artists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle invalid/corrupted image files in ImageDataGenerator.flow\_from\_directory in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433384/handle-invalid-corrupted-image-files-in-imagedatagenerator-flow-from-directory-i)