# Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required

Tags: python, tensorflow

I built a simple CNN model and it raised below errors:

```
Epoch 1/10
235/235 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 540.2643 - accuracy: 0.4358
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-ab88232c98aa> in <module>()
     15     train_ds,
     16     validation_data=val_ds,
---> 17     epochs=epochs
     18 )

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required.
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_test_function_2924]

Function call stack:
test_function
```

The code I wrote is quite simple and standard. Most of them are just directly copied from the official website. It raised this error before the first epoch finish. I am pretty sure that the images are all png files. The train folder does not contain anything like text, code, except imgages. I am using Colab. The version of `tensorlfow` is 2.5.0. Appreciate for any help.

```py
data_dir = './train'

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir, 
    subset='training',
    validation_split=0.2,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    seed=42
)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir, 
    subset='validation',
    validation_split=0.2,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    seed=42
)

model = Sequential([
    layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(image_size, image_size, 3)),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(num_classes)
    ])

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=epochs
)
```

Comment: It's for your validation data. Have you checked also the validation directory images?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated the `val_ds` part. After I comment the `validation_data=val_ds` line, the code suddenly works. The validation data is just split from the same train folder. So they are all png files. I have no idea why this happen.

Comment: Since you have set seed, it returns always the same samples. So, maybe the corrupted image always lies in validation dataset. check this answer, to how handle corrupt files. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52433477/2423278

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. Some of my images in the validation set is not well formatted.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Some of your files in the validation folder are not in the format accepted by Tensorflow ( `JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP`), or may be corrupted. The extension of a file is indicative only, and does not enforce anything on the content of the file.

You might be able to find the culprit using the [`imghdr` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html) from the python standard library, and a simple loop.

```
from pathlib import Path
import imghdr

data_dir = "/home/user/datasets/samples/"
image_extensions = [".png", ".jpg"]  # add there all your images file extensions

img_type_accepted_by_tf = ["bmp", "gif", "jpeg", "png"]
for filepath in Path(data_dir).rglob("*"):
    if filepath.suffix.lower() in image_extensions:
        img_type = imghdr.what(filepath)
        if img_type is None:
            print(f"{filepath} is not an image")
        elif img_type not in img_type_accepted_by_tf:
            print(f"{filepath} is a {img_type}, not accepted by TensorFlow")
```

This should print out whether you have files that are not images, or that are not what their extension says they are, and not accepted by **TF**. Then you can either get rid of them or convert them to a format that TensorFlow supports.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. Some of my images in the validation set is not well formatted.

Comment: Such an underrated saviour comment, going straight to my gist stash and this is gonna remain in my AI / ML Stack for a Long time, thanks!

Comment: I used like 3 different ways to filter none images, or stuff, and thye still missed jpg files that where not able to be opened. This solution worked wonders for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

TensorFlow has some strictness when dealing with image formats. This should guide in deleting the bad images. Some times your data set may even run well with, for instance Torch but will generate a format error with Tf. Nonetheless, it is best practice to always carryout preprocessing on the images to  ensure a robust, safe and standard model.

```
from pathlib import Path
import imghdr

from pathlib import Path
import imghdr

img_link=list(Path("/home/user/datasets/samples/").glob(r'**/*.jpg'))

count_num=0
for lnk in img_link:
    binary_img=open(lnk,'rb')
    find_img=tf.compat.as_bytes('JFIF') in binary_img.peek(10)#The JFIF is a JPEG File Interchange Format (JFIF). It is a standard which we gauge if an image is corrupt or substandard
    if not find_img:
        count_num+=1
        os.remove(str(lnk))
print('Total %d pcs image delete from Dataset' % count_num)
#this should help you delete the bad encoded
```

Comment: Worked for me, thank you a lot man, I was like 3 hours stuck on a similar issue. god bless you :)

Comment: I am glad it helped you. All the best David.

Answer (score 1):

this should work fine, the same for supported types ... ex for png :

```
image = tf.io.read_file("im.png")
image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=3)
```

Comment: Worked for me for jpeg

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I went through a lot of answers above and none of them worked for me. So, I wrote the training loop inside the try except blocks and the batch that has these problems will be skipped. Please note: this is not a direct solution.

```
iterator = iter(preprocessed_train_dataset)
max_iterations = len(preprocessed_train_dataset)
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))
    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    i = 0
    while i < max_iterations:
        print("Currently running {} batch".format(i))
        try:
            i = i + 1
            x_batch_train, y_batch_train = next(iterator)
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)
                loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)

            grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))

            # Log every 200 batches.
            if i % 200 == 0:
                print(
                    "Training loss (for one batch) at step %d: %.4f"
                    % (i, float(loss_value))
                )
                print("Seen so far: %s samples" % ((i + 1) * batch_size))

            train_acc = train_acc_metric.result()
            print("Training acc over epoch: %.4f" % (float(train_acc),))

            # Reset training metrics at the end of each epoch
            train_acc_metric.reset_states()
            for x_batch_val, y_batch_val in preprocessed_val_dataset:
                val_logits = model(x_batch_val, training=False)
                # Update val metrics
                val_acc_metric.update_state(y_batch_val, val_logits)
            val_acc = val_acc_metric.result()
            val_acc_metric.reset_states()
            print("Validation acc: %.4f" % (float(val_acc),))
        except Exception as e:
            continue

# Evaluate the model
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(preprocessed_test_dataset)
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers you can use the [`imghdr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html) built-in Python module to guess the image format and assert that it is not corrupted and that is matches the file extension.

However, starting from Python 3.11 `imghdr` is deprecated ([PEP 594](https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#imghdr)) and will be removed in Python 3.13 due to its limited number of formats supported and its limited functionality.

three alternatives are listed in the PEP: [`filetype`](https://pypi.org/project/filetype/), [`puremagic`](https://pypi.org/project/puremagic/) and [`python-magic`](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/).

Here is an example use with `filetype`:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import filetype


# RFC image file extensions supported by TensorFlow
img_exts = {"png", "jpg", "gif", "bmp"}

path = Path("train")

for file in path.iterdir():
    if file.is_dir():
        continue

    ext = filetype.guess_extension(file)

    if ext is None:
        print(f"'{file}': extension cannot be guessed from content")
    elif ext not in img_exts:
        print(f"'{file}': not a supported image file")
```