# InvalidArgumentError: jpeg::Uncompress failed. Invalid JPEG data or crop window. [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Hi I am getting the error

> InvalidArgumentError: jpeg::Uncompress failed. Invalid JPEG data or
> crop window.   [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
> [Op:IteratorGetNext]

after running the code below. The error is coming from the line,

`for image_batch, label_batch in test_dataset`

May I know why does this error appear? thanks

```
BATCH_SIZE = 32
IMG_SIZE = (224, 224)

train_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(data_dir,
                                              shuffle=True,
                                              label_mode = 'categorical',
                                              validation_split = 0.2,
                                              batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                              seed = 42,
                                              subset = "training",
                                              image_size=IMG_SIZE
                                             )

validation_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(data_dir,
                                              shuffle=True,
                                              label_mode = 'categorical',
                                              validation_split = 0.2,
                                              batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                              seed = 42,
                                              subset = "validation",
                                              image_size=IMG_SIZE
                                             )

train_size = int(0.8 * len(train_dataset))
test_dataset = train_dataset.skip(train_size)    

y_pred_species = []  # store predicted labels
y_pred_diseases = []
y_true = []  # store true labels
    
# iterate over the dataset
for image_batch, label_batch in test_dataset:   # use dataset.unbatch() with repeat
    # append true labels
    y_true.append(label_batch)
    # compute predictions
    preds = model.predict(image_batch)
    # append predicted labels
    y_pred_species.append(np.argmax(preds[0], axis = - 1))
    y_pred_diseases.append(np.argmax(preds[1], axis = - 1))
    
# convert the true and predicted labels into tensors
correct_labels = tf.concat([item for item in y_true], axis = 0)
correct_labels = np.argmax(correct_labels, axis=1)
predicted_species_labels = tf.concat([item for item in y_pred_species], axis = 0)
predicted_diseases_labels = tf.concat([item for item in y_pred_diseases], axis = 0)
```

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68192520/3595907)

Comment: @DrBwts not able to, all the images seem to have correct extension

Comment: They migt have the correct extension but some of the images might be corrupted or maybe mislabled.