# Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required. [[{{node DecodeJpeg}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, model

heres the code:

```
encode_train = sorted(set(img_name_vector))
image_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(encode_train)
image_dataset = image_dataset.map(load_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE).batch(64)

%%time
for img, path in tqdm(image_dataset):
  batch_features = image_features_extract_model(img)
  batch_features = tf.reshape(batch_features,(batch_features.shape[0], -1, batch_features.shape[3]))

  for bf, p in zip(batch_features, path):
    path_of_feature = p.numpy().decode("utf-8")
    np.save(path_of_feature, bf.numpy())
```

I also checked whether the images are sutible for tenserflow through this code, and all of the images were good.

```
from pathlib import Path
import imghdr

data_dir = "./new_google_images/"
image_extensions = [".png", ".jpg"]  # add there all your images file extensions

img_type_accepted_by_tf = ["bmp", "gif", "jpeg", "png"]

for filepath in Path(data_dir).rglob("*"):
    if filepath.suffix.lower() in image_extensions:
        img_type = imghdr.what(filepath)
        if img_type is None:
            print(f"{filepath} is not an image")
        elif img_type not in img_type_accepted_by_tf:
            print(f"{filepath} is a {img_type}, not accepted by TensorFlow")
```

any sugesstions please?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68192520/11103705

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you should use `print()` and display `path` when you load in tensorflow - this way you could see which file makes problem and you could check if it is not bloken and/or remove it from folder. Shortly: you have to learn to debug code - and you may use `print()` for this..

Comment: Thank you guys, well it seems that some of the pictures weren't the same as Tensoerflow accepted so I changed the way the pictures been downloading