# Tensorflow InvalidArgumentError : Input is empty

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, tensorflow-datasets

After reviewing the forum, I did not find the resolution to my problem.
I am working currently on the realization of an OCR algorithm to recognize handwritting. For this, I am working with tensorflow but it brings some difficulties:

- I have a folder containing the images of my dataset
- I realize a reading and transformation of all the images in a dataset tensorflow

--> When I am iterating on my dataset set, the following error is happening (which prevent the execution of any prediction algorithm):

```
for X_t,y_t in dataset_train:
  pass

InvalidArgumentError: Input is empty.
     [[{{function_node __inference_load_image_130965}}{{node DecodePng}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

I'm guessing that my problem is coming from the reading of one of my image but I can't find the error.
I am looking for a solution to remove the bad image from my tensor or to avoid adding the bad image to my tensor during the preprocessing.

My transformation function is as follow:

```
@tf.function

def load_image(filepath):

    im = tf.io.read_file(filepath)

    im = tf.image.decode_png(im, channels=0)

    return im

@tf.function

def preprocess(filepath, imgSize=(32, 128), dataAugmentation=False, scale=0.8, isthreshold=False):

    img = load_image(filepath)/255

    # there are damaged files in IAM dataset - just use black image instead

    if img is None:

        img = tf.ones([imgSize[0], imgSize[1], 1])

        print("None")

    if dataAugmentation:

        stretch = scale*(tf.random.uniform([1], 0, 1)[0] - 0.3) # -0.5 .. +0.5

        wStretched = tf.maximum(int(float(tf.shape(img)[0]) * (1 + stretch)), 1) # random width, but at least 1

        img = tf.image.resize(img, (wStretched, tf.shape(img)[1])) # stretch horizontally by factor 0.5 .. 1.5

    (wt, ht) = imgSize

    w, h = float(tf.shape(img)[0]), float(tf.shape(img)[1])

    fx = w / wt

    fy = h / ht

    f = tf.maximum(fx, fy)

    newSize = (tf.maximum(tf.minimum(wt, int(w / f)), 1), tf.maximum(tf.minimum(ht, int(h / f)), 1)) # scale according to f (result at least 1 and at most wt or ht)

    img = tf.image.resize(img, newSize)

    dx = wt - newSize[0]

    dy = ht - newSize[1]

    if dataAugmentation :

        dx1=0

        dy1=0

        if dx!=0:

            dx1 = tf.random.uniform([1], 0, dx, tf.int32)[0]

        if dy!=0:

            dy1 = tf.random.uniform([1], 0, dy, tf.int32)[0]

        img = tf.pad(img[..., 0], [[dx1, dx-dx1], [dy1, dy-dy1]], constant_values=1)

    else :

        img = tf.pad(img[..., 0], [[0, dx], [0, dy]], constant_values=1)

    if isthreshold:

        return tf.expand_dims(1-(1-img)*tf.cast(img < 0.8, tf.float32), -1)

    return tf.expand_dims(img, -1)
```

You will find below a link to my google colab to allow you to execute direclty my code (execute the first seven lines):
[MY GOOGLE COLAB](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VW_mJe3Q88R2dkbFOTlEm_8hgffwgSzS?usp=sharing)

Comment: That answer might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68192520/7370153. It's a different issue, but I would guess that the solution might also work in your case.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.
It's working very well, thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

I use a bit of time on random functions and the result you need to understand that image augmentation makes learning on the training neurons but it creates difficult for them each function. ( I am also working on some simple tasks ) - see your output from the stretches Fn.

Sample: It is as a baby when you attached a mustache on, you need to tell them something else then it creates difficulty for NN to learn.
Simple hug told your voices but action perform after screens, benches your cheek and twisted.

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
PATH = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Pikaploy', '*.tif')
PATH_2 = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Candidt Kibt', '*.tif')
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH)
files_2 = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH_2)

list_file = []
list_file_actual = []
list_label = []
list_label_actual = [ 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt' ]
for file in files.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    image = tfio.experimental.color.rgba_to_rgb( image, name='rgba_to_rgb' )
    list_file.append(image)
    list_label.append(1)
    
for file in files_2.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    image = tfio.experimental.color.rgba_to_rgb( image, name='rgba_to_rgb' )
    list_file.append(image)
    list_label.append(9)

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
loggings = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\loggings.log"

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)
    
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

def image_augmentation( list_file ):

    list_picture = []
    icount = 0
    
    for image in list_file:
    
        g = tf.random.Generator.from_seed(1234)
        g.reset_from_seed( 1235 + icount )
        temp = tf.random.uniform( shape=(4, 1), minval=0, maxval=6, dtype=tf.dtypes.int64,seed=1235 + icount,name="random" )
        arg = tf.math.argmax( temp ).numpy()[0]
        result = temp[arg].numpy()[0]
        icount = icount + 1

        if result % 6 == 0 :
            layer = tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(.5, .2)
            image = layer( image ).numpy()
            list_picture.append( image )
        elif result % 5 == 0 :
            image = tf.image.random_hue(image, 0.2).numpy()
            image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image, 1).numpy()
            list_picture.append( image )
        elif result % 4 == 0 :
            image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, 5, 10, 1).numpy()
            image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image, 1).numpy()
            list_picture.append( image )
        elif result % 3 == 0 :
            image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image, 1).numpy()
            image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, 5, 10, 1).numpy()
            list_picture.append( image )
        elif result % 2 == 0 :
            image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image, 1).numpy()
            image = tf.image.random_hue(image, 0.2).numpy()
            list_picture.append( image )
        else :
            list_picture.append( image )

    return list_picture

list_file = image_augmentation( list_file )
    
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(10, 1, 32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant(list_label, shape=(10, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Callback
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        # if( logs['loss'] <= 0.2 ):
            # self.model.stop_training = True
        if( logs['accuracy'] >= 0.95 ):
            self.model.stop_training = True
    
custom_callback = custom_callback()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 32, 32, 3 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( dataset, batch_size=100, epochs=10000, callbacks=[custom_callback] )
model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

plt.figure(figsize=(5,2))
plt.title("Actors recognitions")
for i in range(len(list_file)):
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        list_file[i],
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )
    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
    plt.subplot(5, 2, i + 1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(list_file_actual[i])
    plt.xlabel(str(round(score[tf.math.argmax(score).numpy()].numpy(), 2)) + ":" +  str(list_label_actual[tf.math.argmax(score)]))
    
plt.show()

input('...')
```

Result:

```
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 27ms/step - loss: 0.4422 - accuracy: 0.9000
Epoch 21/10000
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 26ms/step - loss: 0.4113 - accuracy: 0.9000
Epoch 22/10000
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 26ms/step - loss: 0.3804 - accuracy: 0.9000
Epoch 23/10000
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 26ms/step - loss: 0.3461 - accuracy: 1.0000
```

[image: Sample]