# INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I wrote a standard code and when I run this command ( model. fit) I have the error above.
I know that most of my dataset is in jpg format and jpg is not accepted by TensorFlow. My dataset is about skin diseases and it has many formats like(jpg, png, jpeg) because it is a custom dataset. How can I convert all my datasets to accepted formats like(png, jpeg).And here is my full code:

```
train = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  '/content/drive/MyDrive/skin',
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(256, 256),
  batch_size=32)
val = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  '/content/drive/MyDrive/skin',
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(256, 256),
  batch_size=32)
class_names = train.class_names
print(class_names)
num_classes = len(class_names)
size = (250, 250)

train = train.map(lambda x, y: (tf.image.resize(x, size), y))
val = val.map(lambda x, y: (tf.image.resize(x, size), y))

base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetV2L(
    include_top=False,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_shape=(250,250,3),
    classifier_activation="softmax",
    include_preprocessing=True,
)
base_model.trainable = False
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(250, 250, 3))
# We make sure that the base_model is running in inference mode here,
# by passing `training=False`. This is important for fine-tuning, as you will
# learn in a few paragraphs.
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)  # Regularize with dropout
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
epochs=30
history = model.fit(train, epochs=epochs, validation_data=val)
```

I saw this code below but i don't want to delete the images in jpg format.

```
from pathlib import Path
import imghdr

from pathlib import Path
import imghdr

img_link=list(Path("/home/user/datasets/samples/").glob(r'**/*.jpg'))

count_num=0
for lnk in img_link:
    binary_img=open(lnk,'rb')
    find_img=tf.compat.as_bytes('JFIF') in binary_img.peek(10)#The JFIF is a JPEG File Interchange Format (JFIF). It is a standard which we gauge if an image is corrupt or substandard
    if not find_img:
        count_num+=1
        os.remove(str(lnk))
print('Total %d pcs image delete from Dataset' % count_num)
#this should help you delete the bad encoded
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191448/unknown-image-file-format-one-of-jpeg-png-gif-bmp-required)

Comment: No, I want to convert images in jpg format to the accepted format not to delete the images in jpg format. thanks for your comment @YScharf

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You are following an incorrect assumption, JPEG is the format, .jpg and .jpeg are the possible file extensions and both are supported, you have a different problem.

Comment: you are right. but i still have this problem as shown below. Any Suggestions please! InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required.
  [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
  [[IteratorGetNext]]
  (1) CANCELLED:  Function was cancelled before it was started
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_65712]

Answer (score 0):

Convert all images to `png` by doing the following:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

images_list = os.listdir(images_dir)

for img in images_list:
    image_pil = Image.open(images_dir+img)

    image_pil.save(images_dir+img.split('.')[0]+'.png')
```

Comment: I put( images_dir=''/content/drive/MyDrive/skin') and 'skin' is my dataset. Then I have an error "No such file or directory" what should I do? thanks again                             @YScharf

Comment: `images_dir` is not the name of an argument. I used it as an `alias` for the directory. Just start by getting `os.listdir` to work.