# How can I debug the data iterator in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, debugging, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am using a tf.data.Iterator for my training in tensorflow with where the the `get_next()` function fails.

Do anyone know how I can debug inside the `get_next()` function?

The `get_next()` function fails due to:

```
  ) = self.dataloaders["train"].get_next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 819, in get_next
    return self._next_internal()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 749, in _next_internal
    ret = gen_dataset_ops.iterator_get_next(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py", line 3017, in iterator_get_next
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 7209, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_8_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Invalid PNG data, size 1160
         [[{{function_node __inference_process_row_2052}}{{node DecodePng}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

Which I think is some corrupted data, but it will be hard to find since I am using a high amount of data. (I am using tensorflow 2.10)

Comment: That answer might help you to find bad data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68192520/7370153